# Epsilon-delta proof of the existence of the limit of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, continuity

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \rightarrow L$ and the function $f$ is continuous at $L$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) \rightarrow f(L)$$

$\underline{Proof.}$

Let $n, N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $f$ is continuous (meaning small changes in input result in small changes in output),

then $\exists n > N$ such that $|f(a_n) - f(L)| < \delta$.

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) \rightarrow f(L)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: what is your definition of continuity?

Comment: I have noticed that you are quite prolific asker. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.

Take $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $L,$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(L)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-L|<\delta$.

Can you use the definition of sequence convergence to get the rest of the way?

Comment: Right, but what precisely is the definition of sequence convergence? Just that there exists an $x > X : |f(x) - f(L)| < \delta$?

Comment: Not at all. When we say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L,$ what do we mean? What definition were you given?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/f/12/mz8n.png/

Comment: Use the more precise version. Since $\delta>0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=L,$ then there exists an $N$ such that...what?